# NSFetchedResultsController with NSPredicate in Two Different UIViewControllers - NSRangeException

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two different views, controlled by two different view controllers. Each view has a UITableView inside it. Each UITableView is hooked to a NSFetchedResultsController. In View 1, I do not want to narrow my FRC results, so I do not use a predicate. In View 2, I use a predicate to get certain objects based on a BOOL (aka NSNumber!) value. But when I try to use this predicate, I get an NSRangeException (index 1 beyond bounds) when I segue to View 2. It also throws that exception when I switch the predicates (predicate on View 1, no predicate on View 2). And again the exception comes when I segue to View 2. There are cases where it is successful (neither of which is what I want):

1) I do not use any predicate for either fetch request.

2) I use the same predicate for the fetch request for both View 1 and View 2.

Some code for your enjoyment:

In View1.m:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [CoreDataHelper getContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"EditableSong" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"dateModified" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:5];
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

In View2.m

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [CoreDataHelper getContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"EditableSong" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"dateModified" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"collaborative == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:myPredicate];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:5];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
NSLog(@"here");
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

And this is where the green error arrow (SIGABRT) points to (this code is the same in View1 and View2 by the way):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];
SongTableViewCell *cell = (SongTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    EditableSong *song = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];//<<<------HERE!!! SIGABRT
    song.audioPlayer = [[AudioPlayer alloc] initWithSong:song];
    cell = [[SongTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier editableSong:song andVC:self];
    UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [playButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainmenuplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(300.0f, 15.0f, 65.0f, 65.0f);
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playSong:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:playButton];
}
return cell;
```

}

Thanks!

**Update 1**

Here is my numberOfRowsInSection method (again, same for both classes):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
id  sectionInfo =
[[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
NSLog(@"%i", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

}

For reference, that log is supposed to print 3 in View1 and 1 in View2, but it prints 3 in both.

Comment: Since your are getting `NSRangeException (index 1 beyond bounds)` it very likely means the the "array" inside the crashing `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't have the data you are trying to access. I would suggest to verify if your table view sections/rows correspond correctly to data available inside the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Why are you not queueing your cells properly? If they all look the same, you should give them the same identifier. /(Change the initializer to something generic.) Also, you should separate your cell creation code from the cell customization code (within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I changed my cell identifiers to something generic like you said.

Could you explain more about what you mean by separating the cell creation with the cell customization? Where else would I create a button for the cell that references a method in the current class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

Had to change the cache to nil.

See this post:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/delete-the-nsfetchedresultscontroller-cache-before-changing-the-nspredicate

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are returning the wrong number of cells. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` wants to create a cell, but there is no `objectAtIndexPath`.

So you will need to check your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: Thanks for you initial help Mundi. But could you tell me more? I have added some information about my `numberOfRowsInSection` method.
Thanks!

Comment: It should be `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> info`.

Comment: HHmmm. That didn't work. If I understood you correctly, I changed my code to this:

`id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =
    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];`